# ggplot - prevent ordering of character or factor x-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

Consider the following data frame being plotted as `geom_line`:

```
mydata <- data.frame(X = c('1 Dog', '2 Dog', '3 Dog', '4 Dog', '1 Frog', '2 Frog', '1 Cat', '2 Cat'), Y = sample(1:3, 8, replace = T))
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = X, y = Y, group = 1)) + geom_line() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
print(myplot)
```

The plot orders the x-axis by number and alphabetically. How can I prevent this, such that the graph is plotted in the order as it is in the data frame? Converting `X` to a character does not help. I cannot order the x-axis ticks manually as my original dataset has thousands of entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an ordered factor to prevent the order. For example

```
mydata$x <- factor(maydata$x, 
                   levels = c('1 Dog', '2 Dog', '3 Dog', '4 Dog', '1 Frog', '2 Frog', '1 Cat', '2 Cat'), 
                   ordered = T)
```

In the levels argument you should mention the levels in the specific order you want to see in the plot. The argument `ordered = T` preserves the order.

Comment: I guess  `mydata$X <- factor(mydata$X, levels = unique(mydata$X))` is better since OP has thousand of enteries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with the addition of @RonakShah
Definitely need to use `unique()` due to the number of levels within my original dataset.